# Why is dropna() and replace() methods not working for missing data in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have started with a data science course which requires me to handle missing data either by deleting the row containing NaN in "price" subset or replacing the NaN with some mean value. However both of my dropna() and replace() doesn't seem to work. What could be the problem?

I went through a lot of solutions on stackoverflow but my problem was not solved. I also tried going through pandas.pydata.org to look for solution where I learnt about different arguments for dropna() like thresh, how='any', etc but nothing helped.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np


url="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data"
df=pd.read_csv(url,header=None)


'''
Our data comes without any header or column name,hence we assign each column a header name.
'''


headers=["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration","num-of-doors","body-style","drive-wheels","engnie-location","wheel-base","length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type","num-of-cylinders","engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower","peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]
df.columns=headers


'''
Now that we have to eliminate rows containing NaN or ? in "price" column in our data
'''

df.dropna(subset=["price"], axis=0, inplace=True) 

df.head(12)

#or

df.dropna(subset=["price"], how='any') 

df.head(12)

#also to replace

mean=df["price"].mean()

df["price"].replace(np.nan,mean)

df.head(12)
```

It was expected that all the rows containig NaN or "?" in the "price" column to be deleted for dropna() or replaced for replace(). However there seems to be no change in data.

Comment: Try: `df['price'] = df['price'].fillna(df['price'].mean())`? Also replace method won't change the dataframe, so it should be assigned back: `df['price']=df["price"].replace(np.nan,mean)`. Similarly for `dropna`, assign back unless you're using `inplace`.

Comment: Hello can you print out `df.head(12)` before your processing, and maybe `df.info()` to get data type info?

Comment: does `'drop.na()` take an `inplace` argument? if so, that's what you need to pass or re-assign the argument to the df like Mohit has stated above.. Nice question btw! make sure you give us a sample of your data and expected output next time.

Comment: @Datanovice the first `df.dropna` has `inplace=True` already.

Comment: can you post sample data and an expected output?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add an example dataframe for which this problem shows up. For all we know, you have simply mistyped the column name.

Comment: Dear all, I have made the edits by adding my dataframe. The problem is the 9th row of the data has a cell under 'price' column with "?" or NaN value. I expect that row to be completely deleted (for dropna() method) or changed with some other value(for replace() method). Please help me explaining where I am going wrong.

Comment: @MohitMotwani Thanks, but the data seems unchanged. Something's still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code to drop ? value as following:

```
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna()
```

`to_numeric` method converts argument to a numeric type.

And, `coerce` sets invalids as NaN.

Then, `dropna` can clear records include NaN.